# Turn off zooming when in portrait mode

Tags: javascript, ipad

Hello i am using this zoom javascript code to zoom my div depending on the screen size it works perfectly but i would like it so when I set an ipad to portrait mode it stops the zoom script from working. here is the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var minW = 1800;

$(function () {
CheckSizeZoom()
$('#divWrap').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
$(window).resize(CheckSizeZoom)

function CheckSizeZoom() {
if ($(window).width() < minW) {
var zoomLev = $(window).width() / minW;

if (typeof (document.body.style.zoom) != "undefined") {
$(document.body).css('zoom', zoomLev);
}
else {
// Mozilla doesn't support zoom, use -moz-transform to scale and compensate for lost width
$('#divWrap').css('-moz-transform', "scale(" + zoomLev + ")");
$('#divWrap').width($(window).width() / zoomLev + 10);
$('#divWrap').css('position', 'relative');
$('#divWrap').css('left', (($(window).width() - minW - 16) / 2) + "px");
$('#divWrap').css('top', "-19px");
$('#divWrap').css('position', 'relative');
}
}
else {
$(document.body).css('zoom', '');
$('#divWrap').css('position', '');
$('#divWrap').css('left', "");
$('#divWrap').css('top', "");
$('#divWrap').css('-moz-transform', "");
$('#divWrap').width("");
}
}
</script>
```

cheers

Comment: I must say your question title is kind of misleading...

Comment: i dont know how else to describe it

Comment: Maybe "Turn off zooming when in portrait mode"

Answer (score 0):

Check the `$(window).width()` against the `$(window).height()` to determine the device orientation.

Another tip is to chain your jQuery calls like this `$('#divWrap').css('position', '').css('left', '').css('top', '');` for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

To detect portrait-mode WDever already presented the correct answer.
Yet I do not encourage either of the two ways of using the .css() function in this case.
You may pass an object to this function like:

```
$('#divWrap').css({
    position: '',
    left: '',
    top: ''
});
```

This way you keep your code clean, short and easy to read.

Comment: where would i place this sorry im quite basic with javascript

Comment: You got lines of code looking like this: 
"$(document.body).css('zoom', '');" 
You could get all those .css() into a single one using the example presented above

Comment: Totally copy-pasted the exact wrong line, as that element only receives a single change... Obviously I meant to copy-paste a line like this: "$('#divWrap').css('position', '');"

Comment: Thanks! That is a lot better, I forgot you could do that.

Comment: is there not a way i can set the media query as a variable and then say if media query is equal to max-width: 768px then dont run the javascript?

Comment: Mobile devices are heavily varying in terms of screen-resolution. Even the iPads in comparance to the iPads - you will not be able to do that precisely for more than one device. Portrait-mode basicly means that the resolution will change from a "Width>Height"-ratio to a "Height>Width"-ratio. Based on the changing ratio you can run the script or not run it. Kinda like 'if ($(window).height>$(window).width) {}'